# How to make http://deco.gs/ cells in a specific row equal height?

Tags: css

I like the http://deco.gs/ CSS grid system. I would like to make cells in one of rows in my
actual layout equal height. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve it? I went through many
articles on how to do equal height boxes/columns but I could not find one fitting the http://deco.gs/ the best.

Thanks for your ideas.

--
hex

Comment: I don't understand how this is better than just using a table.

Comment: Using tables for layouts is formally wrong. Or, if you mean the CSS display "table" properties, those do not work in all browsers.

Comment: Any sort of table should be used for data. I use tables for data and I've never had a problem.

Comment: But I do not use it for data. I use it for website layout (that's what this framework was made for). It suites my needs very well, except the fact I realized I need cells in one of the rows to be equal height. I hope the misunderstanding is cleared now.

Answer (score 0):

You are very unclear as to how you are wanting to achieve this. Could you not just use something like this? [JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zUKV8/](http://jsfiddle.net/zUKV8/)

Comment: It's a rough template but this is how I interpret what you are telling us.

Comment: I was long time looking for simple and elegant way for building grid layouts. The http://deco.gs/ is very simple and really elegant. What I need, the only thing, is to achieve that cells in one of the rows in my layout will have equal height. I do not want to use any other framework (even not http://960.gs/) while this one is working well. The author of it just did not published any way to make equal height cells in some row and that's what I am looking for and that's how the question was laid. My idea is to wrap the row or cells with "something" causing the needed effect or special cell def.

Answer (score 0):

IN PLONE: Okay, that works for me (Chrome - no other browsers tested yet!):

```
#portal-columns {
    height: 100%;
}

#portal-column-one {
    position:absolute;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

So a background color in the equal height as the longest column is possible.